# Gnuplot points overlapping the axis

Tags: gnuplot, axis, point, overlap

I've searched about this but I can't find anyone having the same problem (or it may be something really trivial). 
Case is, when plotting in gnuplot, the points with the same value as the axis overlap this one and is results quite ugly.

[image: See image]

I've tried to fix it by setting the range but it doesn't help. Is there any way to plot the point such that, as it appears at the image, half of it would stay in the graphic, while the other half would get under the axis and the exterior blank space? Thanks!

Comment: Try `set offsets first 0.1,0,0,0` to add a bit more space on the left. Or with `set border front` the border is drawn on top of the point. `set clip points` would remove that point on the axis completly.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but the three ways work! A note about the first one, though: putting `first` was not necessary for me, just `set offsets 0.1,0,0,0` works. (Also, one has to be careful with it's usage, not every type of graphic looks well that way.)

Comment: Why not setting another type of border? For example `set border 5` would make disappear vertical borders, or directly `unset border`, which will leave your tics. In this last case i recommend using `set grid` so you will have a dashed grey transparent line instead of a black solid line.

Comment: @opisthofulax That's another valid option, thank you!

Comment: @stonebird check `help offsets`. You can also give a value relative to the graph size, e.g. `set offsets graph 0.05,0,0,0` which will be independent of the absolute values of the first axis range.